# Not able to authenticate using the django rest framework (request.user = AnonymousUser)

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to configure authentication for the incoming request but I am not able to understand the required steps to achieve it.

I have followed the steps provided in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)

First, I edited the `setting.py` for the auth settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    ...,
]

    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
            'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        )
    }
```

In the `view.py`:

```
@csrf_exempt
def uuid_details(request, uuid):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        print "user: " + str(request.user)  #  user: AnonymousUser
```

So when I invoke above rest API, in the above line I am getting output as `AnonymousUser`. As per my understanding, I should receive the authenticated `User` object.

I am able to retrieve the token and passing it to the rest API.

```
>>> Token.objects.get(user=user)
<Token: 95119884347cf000caab9d2596b9a18a9103f1db>
```

So, I am not able to understand how the authentication works in Django rest framework.

Comment: how do you make the `request` to the view that has `AnonymousUser`?

Comment: @iulian following is the request curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/uuid/O5gn2Pl7RTqQc7PR4HDQjw/details/ -H 'Authorization: Token 95119884347cf000caab9d2596b9a18a9103f1db'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a regular Django view, so none of the rest framework authentication code will run.

```
def uuid_details(request, uuid):
```

You could use the `api_view` decorator to turn this into a rest framework view.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['GET'])
def uuid_details(request, uuid):
    return Response({"message": "user: " + str(request.user)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. @csrf_exempt doesn't work on DRF views. It's for raw Django ones.
2. You didn't use the [DRF decorator for function views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view)

It should work once those two points are fixed.